# Specific tasks reminder for deployment

Tags: python, git, deployment, fabric

For several web projects which I deploy with git and Fabric, I sometimes have specific tasks to do.

Examples:

- Manual migration to run
- Vendors to update
- Cron tasks to add
- etc...

There are some tasks that I intentionally don't automate because quite unusual.

I'm thinking about managing a TODO file checked in the repository which I would read from my fabfile to remind me the specific things linked to new version to do before or after the deployment.

Is there a common way to manage these deployment specific reminders ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I use (until I find better)

With Fabric:

```
from fabric.colors import red
from os.path import isfile

def dontforget(force=False):
    if not force and isfile('TODO'):
        print(red("/* TODO ************************/"))
        local('cat TODO')
        print(red("/*******************************/"))
        exit(0)
    print(green("Ok I'm good"))
```

Called from my main `deploy` function

```
def deploy(force=False):
    dontforget(force)
    print(green("Let's deploy that awesome version !"))
    pushpull()
    cacheclear()
# ...
```

If a `TODO` file exists it gets displayed and the program stops

```
$ fab deploy
/* TODO ************************/
- Do this
- Do that
/*******************************/

$ fab deploy:force
Ok I'm good
Let's deploy that awesome version !
```